# Completely disable mouse scrolling in Emacs 25.2.2

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I tried to completely disable mouse scrolling in Emacs 25.2.2 because the cursor often moves unexpectedly. However, the mouse scrolling seems to be taken as `next-line` or `previous-line` in my environment. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the mouse wheel by putting this in your `.emacs` file:

```
(mouse-wheel-mode 0)
```

Another way to do it is to [customize](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) the variables `mouse-wheel-down-event` and `mouse-wheel-up-event` and set them to `nil`. I prefer the first method.

Comment: Excuse me. I didn't mention that I'm using Emacs passing `-nw` flag... Your answer works fine with GUI Emacs, but doesn't work with `emacs -nw` in terminal...

Comment: Are you sure it's not the terminal emulator that scrolls?